# Popping the EXACT same value from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a general list with information:

```
lis = ["Hello", "Hello1", "Test"]
```

Then I have a dictionary with filepathes to .c files as values and keys are extensions of the lis values like:

```
dict1 = {"/****Hello****/":
             ["C://test/hello/one.c",
              "C://test/hello/two.c"],
         "/****Hello1****/":
             ["C://test/helloNext/one.c",
              "C://test/helloNext/two.c"],
         "/****Test****/":
             ["C://test/bye/one.c",
              "C://test/bye/two.c"]}
```

The idea is to replace the keys of dict1 with the values of lis, if values of lis are in the key information.

```
for x in lis:
    for y in dict1.copy():
        if x in y:
            dict1[x] = dict1.pop(y)
```

As far as good but now I found a big problem:

If I do it that way, some information of dict1 are overwritten because in this example, it searches for a key with "Hello" in it and overwrites dict1[0] but also overwrites dict1[1] to "Hello" instead of "Hello1" because it's the first information...

I don't get to a solution on my own. 
I think I am just missing a little bit...

Thanks!

PS: It is not a solution to just cut out special characters from the keys, because it does not look the same for every file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to sort the list based on the length of the elements and process it in the reverse order:

```
lis = ["Hello", "Hello1", "Test"]

dict1 = {"/****Hello****/": ["C://test/hello/one.c", "C://test/hello/two.c"],
         "/****Hello1****/": ["C://test/helloNext/one.c", "C://test/helloNext/two.c"],
         "/****Test****/": ["C://test/bye/one.c", "C://test/bye/two.c"]}

for x in sorted(lis, key=len, reverse=True):
    for y in dict1:
        if x in y and y not in lis:
            dict1[x] = dict1.pop(y)
            break

print(dict1)
# {'Hello1': ['C://test/helloNext/one.c', 'C://test/helloNext/two.c'], 'Hello': ['C://test/hello/one.c', 'C://test/hello/two.c'], 'Test': ['C://test/bye/one.c', 'C://test/bye/two.c']}
```

Comment: Good idea to reverse the entries of lis!! Thanks! But it still overrides the old values, because it loops through the changed list again...

Comment: What do you mean by 'overrides the old values'? The output is a dictionary with the cleaned up keys and their corresponding values..

Comment: Omg sorry I did not see the break in your for loop! Thats the point haha. Thanks a lot that was perfectly what I was searching! :)))

Comment: Actually, it **may** override old values in a Python version where dictionaries don't maintain insertion order (i.e. before 3.6), so good point! I've added an additional check.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your first list by descending length and then create a copy of your original dictionary, moving each element from the first to the new dict.

```
In [1]:

llist = ["a", "aa", "ab", "c"]
dict1 = {"xax": 1, "xaax": 2, "xabx": 3, "xabcx": 4}
llist.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
dict2 = dict()
for key in dict1:
    success = False
    for replace_token in llist:
        if replace_token in key:
            dict2[replace_token] = dict1.get(key)
            success = True
            break
    if not success:
        dict2[key] = dict1.get(key)

print(dict2)
Out [1]:

{'a': 1, 'aa': 2, 'ab': 4}
```

The general problem is in my code, as well as in your example. It is overwriting all previous values. So I suppose those values shall be in a list:

```
In [1]:

from typing import List
llist = ["a", "aa", "ab", "c"]
dict1 = {"xax": 1, "xaax": 2, "xabx": 3, "xabcx": 4}
llist.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
dict2 = dict()
for key in dict1:
    success = False
    for replace_token in llist:
        if replace_token in key:
            current = dict2.get(replace_token, [])
            new = dict1.get(key)
            if isinstance(new, List):
                current.extend(new)
            else:
                current.append(new)
            dict2[replace_token] = current
            success = True
            break
    if not success:
        dict2[key] = dict1.get(key)
print(dict2)
Out [1]:

{'a': [1], 'aa': [2], 'ab': [3, 4]}
```

Comment: Your 2nd code section is what I searched for I think. I have to play a bit with it but thanks a lot to this point! 
To reverse the entries is great!

Comment: The solution of Eugene is what I searched for and is much shorter so I changed it to the correct answer! But I think your solution would work fine too. So thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
lis = ["Hello","Hello1","Test"]

dict1 = {"/****Hello****/": ["C://test/hello/one.c", "C://test/hello/two.c"],
"/****Hello1****/": ["C://test/helloNext/one.c", "C://test/helloNext/two.c"],
"/****Test****/": ["C://test/bye/one.c", "C://test/bye/two.c"]}

dict2 = {}
for x in lis:
    print('x:',x)
    for y in dict1.copy():
        y2 = (y.replace('*', ''))
        y2 = (y2.replace('/', ''))
        if x == y2:
            print(x,y2)
            dict2[x] = dict1[y]

print(dict2)
```

**Alternative:  no using dict2**

```
if x == y2:
            print(x,y2)
            dict1[x] = dict1[y]
            del dict1[y]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'Hello': ['C://test/hello/one.c', 'C://test/hello/two.c'], 'Hello1': ['C://test/helloNext/one.c', 'C://test/helloNext/two.c'], 'Test': ['C://test/bye/one.c', 'C://test/bye/two.c']}
```

Comment: Like I said: Has nothing to do with "*" or "/" but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
lis = ["Hello","Hello1","Test"]
dict1 = {"/****Hello****/": ["C://test/hello/one.c", "C://test/hello/two.c"], "/****Hello1****/": ["C://test/helloNext/one.c", "C://test/helloNext/two.c"], "/****Test****/": ["C://test/bye/one.c", "C://test/bye/two.c"]}
_lis = sorted(lis, key=len, reverse=True)
new_dict = {re.findall('|'.join(_lis), a)[0]:b for a, b in dict1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'Hello': ['C://test/hello/one.c', 'C://test/hello/two.c'], 'Hello1': ['C://test/helloNext/one.c', 'C://test/helloNext/two.c'], 'Test': ['C://test/bye/one.c', 'C://test/bye/two.c']}
```